# Should there be an error if I tried to IF LIST == 'value' in Python?

Tags: python

still learning python and realized my code should not be working but there was no error given.

Suspected wrong code, Example1

```
ListA = [1h]

if ListA == '1h':
 print(True)
else:
 print(False)
```

What I think is correct based on reading up and doing simple logic test, Example2:

```
ListA = [1h]

if '1h' in ListA:
 print(True)
else:
 print(False)
```

I have been running Example1 for quite some time, although I did not notice much undesired output in the grand scheme of things, I just want to be sure which one I should be using.

Comment: Why wrong code ? Just false condition, is a list equal to a string : no. no matter the values

Comment: "Should there be an error" if there was an error, your code would raise one, if it doesn't : there is error

Comment: There may be logical error on your part, depending on what you actually want to check, but syntactically there's no error.

Comment: your statement is false : ListA = [1h] gives 
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I flagged your post

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list and see if the element you are looking for is in the list. Example:

```
ListA = ["1h", "2h"]

for ele in ListA:
    if ele == "1h":
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

You either can use the above example for longer list. In your case, I would use Example 2 that you provide since it is cleaner. Both code achieve the same thing with the same time complexity which is O(N) where N is the number of elements in your array.